# Explanation behind a 'non-irreducible' as a product of irreducible

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, field-theory, unique-factorization-domains

I am currently looking at a proof behind the theorem:

> Every Principal ideal domain is a unique factorisation domain.

In a part of the proof:

"Let $a_{0}$ be an element in the principal ideal domain written as $a_{0}=p_{1}c_{1}$ where $p_{1}$ is irreducible and $c_{1}$ is not a unit. 
If $c_{1}$ is not irreducible then we  can write $c_{1}=p_{2}c_{2}$ where $p_{2}$ is irreducible and $c_{2}$ is not a unit..."

[image]

Can someone shed some light as to how an element that is not an irreducible be written as a product of an element that is an irreducible? I've kept going back to the definition for irreducible but am none the wiser.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you proved before? Maybe it follows from some lemma/theorem that you have proved earlier about PID...

Comment: I have attached a screenshot in the OP

Comment: That was proved in the first paragraph, i.e. ACPP $\Rightarrow$ the divisibility relation is well-founded, so any chain of nontrivial factors eventually stabilizes (at an irreducible element if the chain is maximal). So by continually taking proper factors we will eventually obtain an irreducible factor (without ACCP this process might not termnate).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The author is using the fact that each nonzero nonunit in a PID has at least one irreducible factor (which is the claim in the first paragraph of the attached screenshot).

Comment: Is there anything in the argument that would suggests the p's are prime?

Comment: Not yet. the statement that every $a$ has an irreducible factor holds in any Noetherian ring, as the proof in the first paragraph shows. (we only use the ascending ideal property).

Answer (score 1):

- If $R$ is principal ideal domain, then by definition every ideal is generated by one element.
- Every maximal ideal is prime.
- in integral domain [every prime element is irreducible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prime_element#Irreducible_elements)

Now for arbitrary $a\in R$ that is not unit, there exists maximal ideal such, that $(a)\subset M$, and $\exists m\in R:\ (m) = M$.

$m$ is irreductible, and $a\in (m)$, therefore $\exists t\in R:\ mt=a$.

Comment: I have considered this from a theorem. But no mentioned was made of $p_{i}$ being prime.

Comment: Because author of proof has used different approach pointed out by Pawel: that every PID is noetherian, and reduction ad infinitum would produce infinite chain of ideals - it cannot happen in noetherian ring. I have shown that every nonzero nonunit has irreductible factor as needed. The fact that element in my construction is prime is only auxiliary.